# how to drop mongodb database through window shell file

Tags: windows, mongodb

I am on windows 10 platform, I want to delete my db on daily basis. for that, I will create an executable cron base shell file. but this will not work for me. Any guess why it is not performing the task?

> deletedb.sh (filename with extension)

```
#!/usr/bin/env mongo
var db = new Mongo().getDB("secondary");//secondary is my db name
db.dropDatabase();
```

Comment: Are you sure you want to drop a database daily? There is no undelete option, so this could be a dangerous `cron` job to leave running.

Answer (score 0):

Your example looks like it should work, assuming you don't have authentication enabled and are connecting to a server listening on the default host (localhost) and port (27017).

However, running `new Mongo()` will attempt to create a new connection, which isn't overly useful if you've just connected.

Your example could be simplified to a unix shell incantation:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
mongo localhost/secondary --eval "db.dropDatabase()"
```

If you want extra reassurance that you are dropping the expected database you could explicitly select the db to drop:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
mongo localhost/secondary --eval "db.getSiblingDB('secondary').dropDatabase()"
```

If your intent is to clean up older test data, an alternative approach to consider would be using MongoDB's [TTL (Time-To-Live) indexes](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/expire-data/) to expire data from collections either after a specific number of seconds or at a certain expiry time.